# Passing arguments to an R script from command lines

Tags: sql, r

How to modify the script where the script accepts a table name and the KPI column name which will get added in the table as an calculated output by the script itself.
for example the script is passed with the table name and parameter groupby(Table1, Group No).

here the parameters are passed inside the round brackets above.

Answer (score 0):

if you use cmd try "argparser" library...
Try

```
suppressMessages(library("argparser"))

p <- arg_parser("Enter table and group")
p <- add_argument(p, "--table")
p <- add_argument(p, "--group")


params <- parse_args(p, argv = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE))
```

Now you params may be in

```
params$group
paramp$table
```